# Reading different text file and exctract same index lines

Tags: python

I am not a python programmer. But I need to make a input file for a software. I have a a.txt file and b.txt and each line in a.txt is corresponded to an "indexes" in b.txt.
a.txt:

```
      0          0          0 L M L     41 ACC sh        1.008732   
      1          0          0 L * L     53 NCR sh        1.022706       
      2          1          1 L M L     18 ACC sh        1.025172    
      3          2          2 L M L     17 ACC sh        1.017734     
      4          2          2 L * L     21 NCR sh        1.025410
```

b.txt:

```
#indexes:           0           0           0
       1        -0.375E+04         0.382E+01        
       2        -0.375E+04         0.432E+01        
       3        -0.376E+04         0.353E+01        
#indexes:           1           0           0
       1        -0.635E+04         0.331E+01
       2        -0.235E+04         0.238E+01
#indexes:           2           1           1
       1        -0.735E+04         0.093E+01
#indexes:           3           2           2
       1        -0.835E+04         0.331E+01
       2        -0.035E+04         0.438E+01  
#indexes:           4           2           2
       1        -0.475E+04         0.331E+01
       2        -0.365E+04         0.438E+01
```

I need to extract lines with "ACC" in the 8th column in a.txt and store them in a new a_new.txt.

a_new.txt:

```
  0          0          0 L M L     41 ACC sh        1.008732   
  2          1          1 L M L     18 ACC sh        1.025172    
  3          2          2 L M L     17 ACC sh        1.017734
```

Then read b.txt file, find "indexes" lines and see if the numbers in that line are the the same as ACC lines (first 3 coulmns) then store that index box in b_new.txt:

b_new.txt:

```
#indexes:           0           0           0
   1        -0.375E+04         0.382E+01        
   2        -0.375E+04         0.432E+01        
   3        -0.376E+04         0.353E+01        
#indexes:           2           1           1
   1        -0.735E+04         0.093E+01
#indexes:           3           2           2
   1        -0.835E+04         0.331E+01
   2        -0.035E+04         0.438E+01
```

I would appreciate if any body could help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: Where is your code ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a couple of minutes to do this:

```
import re
f = open('a.txt','r')
a = f.read()
f.close()
a_new = open('a_new.txt','w')
a_new.write('\n'.join(re.findall('(^.*ACC.*$)',a,re.M)))
a_new.close()
f = open('b.txt','r')
b = f.read()
f.close()
with open('b_new.txt','w') as b_new,open('a_new.txt','r') as a_new:
    inds = [x.replace(' ','') for x in re.findall('^\s*(\d\s*\d\s*\d)',a_new.read(),re.M)]
    for ind in inds:
        reg = '(#indexes:\s*{0}\s*{1}\s*{2}[\s\S]*?(?=#indexes|$))'.format(*list(ind))
        matches = re.findall(reg,b)
        b_new.write('\n'.join(matches))
```

after running it, the `a_new.txt` will be like:

```
  0          0          0 L M L     41 ACC sh        1.008732
  2          1          1 L M L     18 ACC sh        1.025172
  3          2          2 L M L     17 ACC sh        1.017734
```

and `b_new.txt` :

```
#indexes:           0           0           0
       1        -0.375E+04         0.382E+01
       2        -0.375E+04         0.432E+01
       3        -0.376E+04         0.353E+01
#indexes:           2           1           1
       1        -0.735E+04         0.093E+01
#indexes:           3           2           2
       1        -0.835E+04         0.331E+01
       2        -0.035E+04         0.438E+01
```

Comment: Do you work for free al the time? I have some work lying around...

Comment: @RickyA , I am a student and I learn by coding the problems in SO, couple of minutes( I don't think writing 5 lines of code was such a waste of time ) wasn't a big deal and yes if your work interests and helps me learn something, I'll be more than happy to help :)